# Asynchronously fetching data from the database

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core, dapper, asp.net-core-webapi

The following C# code is written to fetch the Categories data from SQL Server Database using Asynchronous Task for `HttpGet`. The Dapper library is used as ORM.

I need help to identify whether the Async Task implementation is correct or any better way to implement.

**CategoriesController.cs**

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller 
{
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> FindList(CategorySearchModel searchModel)
  {
    var results = await new CategoryQueryService().FindList();

    return GetHandler(results);
  }

  IActionResult GetHandler(object results)
  {
      return new OkObjectResult(new { results });
  }
}
```

**CategoryQueryService.cs**

```
public class CategoryQueryService : BaseQueryDataStoreAsync<CategoryQueryModel>
{
  public override Task<IEnumerable<CategoryQueryModel>> FindList()
  {
    const string dbConnectionString = "-- db connection string here --";
    const string sql = "SELECT CategoryId, CategoryName FROM Category ORDER BY CategoryName ASC";

    return QueryAsync(dbConnectionString, sql);
  }
}
```

**CategoryQueryModel.cs**

```
public class CategoryQueryModel {
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public int CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseQueryDataStoreAsync.cs**

```
using Dapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public abstract class BaseQueryDataStoreAsync<T> where T : class
{
  public abstract Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindList();

  public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync(string dbConnectionString, string sql)
  {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
    {
      return await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, conditions: null, transaction: null, commandTimeout: null, commandType: null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this work? Because I doubt `QueryAsync<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: **The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code.** Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://CodeReview.meta.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @BCdotWEB it looks like it does, see [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/e199a8713c7942c05ed7dc6af8f389943568ed0f/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L87)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `async/await` usage doesn't look fine because the chain it's incomplete. `FindList` should be `async` and named `FindListAsync` and it should `await` the result from `QueryAsync`.

There are also a few other things that botter me:

- since `BaseQueryDataStoreAsync` is an abstract class then `QueryAsync` should probably be `protected` and not `public` - otherwise someone can use it for any query
- the `CategoryQueryService` should be injected
- the `GetHandler` doesn't look very useful
- making the `dbConnectionString` a `const` is a terrible idea - you could/should use `appSettings.json` to store it and `IConfiguration` or `IOptions` to get it
- setting `QueryAsync`'s default parameters to `null` where they are `null` anyway ([source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/e199a8713c7942c05ed7dc6af8f389943568ed0f/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L87)) is pretty pointless - instead just use the overload with a single parameter.

Comment: `FindListAsync` is public because it is being directly called by the Controller, I will ask a separate question about that. Regarding the `CategoryQueryService`, I will read up. `GetHandler` is used by other endpoints. `dbConnection` is being injected through `IConfiguration` but for this example, I made a `constant`.